# The projection of an unit cube by uniformly random orthogonal pair of unit vectors becomes close to a disc as dimension becomes large.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, geometric-probability

Let $U, V \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are uniformly random orthogonal unit vectors, i.e. $||U||_2=||V||_2=1$ w.p. $1$, $U^{T}V=0$ w.p. $1$ and $(OU,OV)$ is distributed same as $(U,V)$ for all orthogonal $n \times n$ matrices $O$.

Consider the subset of the plane
$$ \mathcal{P}_n := \left\{ (z^{T}U, z^{T}V) : z \in [-1,1]^n \right\}.$$
I am asked to show that for large $n$, $\mathcal{P}_n$ is close to a disc in the sense that $R_n/r_n$ converges in probability to $1$, where
$$ R_n := \sup \left\{||z||_2 : z \in \mathcal{P}_n \right\}, \; r_n := \inf \left\{||z||_2 : z \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \mathcal{P}_n \right\}.$$

It is clear that $R_n \geq r_n$. But I am not sure how to approach the other side. I hope convexity of the set $\mathcal{P}_n$ will be crucial and may be the representation of $(U,V)$ by Gaussian vectors might be helpful. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of $r_n$. Why isn't that always $\infty$?

Comment: Extremely sorry. My mistake. Should have been infimum. Corrected it now.

Comment: For $a\in \mathcal P_n$, there is $z\in[-1,1]^n$ such that $a=[z^TU,z^TV]^T$, hence $\|a\|_2^2=z^TUU^Tz+z^TVV^Tz=z^T (UU^T+VV^T) z$. I think it could be useful to rewrite $r_n$ and $R_n$ as infimum and supremum over $z\in \mathbb R^n$ instead. The sup will be attained at a $z\in\{-1,1\}$ because of the quadratique form $z^TAz$. The inf is a more delicate matter.